# Keep format text in text area rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a form to let users fill in title and body(text area input & store as text in DB).

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :body %>
  <%= f.button :button %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

After saved, when users edit the record again, then I see

[image]

This is what inside the db:

```
"**In this release:**\r\n    \r\n1. One\r\n2. Two\r\n3. Three\r\n    \r\nHello"
```

Look like every `\n` value in body when they display in textarea, it will add some spaces in front of it. Is there anyway to display value in textarea as what users input from before?

Rails 4.2 & Ruby 2.2.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: It's just simple CRUD resources.

Comment: What is in your database? If you start the console and type: `Post.last.body` what is your output?

Comment: @Fietsband I added the value in db in description.

Comment: A newline will never add spaces in front of a 'substring of text (like "1. One"' in a textarea. It must be some sort of html parsing in your rails app / javascript library that's adding the spaces. So like @netcreator says: 'Please show us your code'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I investigated, I found the problem because my current project we have mixed view templates some are erb and some are haml. I have layout in haml `layouts/application_new.html.haml` and `releases/_form.html.erb` for resource view template, then it caused this issue. After I switch `releases/_form.html.erb` to `releases/_form.html.haml`, then everything works great.